# Rails Lockbox - Lockbox Gem - Undefined Method: Decrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, rubygems

I'm new to data security and am trying to integrate the gem [Lockbox](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox) into my Rails app.

My goal is to create a multi-step form that includes encrypted personal information. I am currently doing development and find it extremely helpful to inspect my object on each step. However, upon introduction of Lockbox, I have lost the ability to inspect the object, due to a decryption error.

Unfortunately I haven't found a lot of blogs, posts on stack, or deep documentation to help me with understanding and debugging this and I must not be fully comprehending the source code for the gem.

I have approached solving this issue by decrypting within the view or within the controller and attempting to decrypt various parts of the object in slightly different ways, but get an error either way.

step2.html.erb

```
<% lockbox = Lockbox.new(key: Rails.application.credentials.lockbox[:master_key] ) %>
<% @example_decrypted = lockbox.decrypt(@example.example.attributes) %>
<%= @example_decrypted.inspect %>
```

I am presented with this error on the line that attempts to decrypt the attributes:

> Lockbox::DecryptionError in ExamplesController#step2p
>
> > Decryption failed

I've also tried the following on step2.html.erb, which also produces the above error

```
<%= @example_decrypted = (@example.example.attributes.encrypted_attribute) %>
```

Again, the above worked just fine before the introduction of encryption to the model.

The following code works as expected within my rails console

```
lockbox = Lockbox.new(key: Rails.application.credentials.lockbox[:master_key] )
=> #<Lockbox::Encryptor:0x000055c8f3faf458 @encode=nil, @boxes=[#<Lockbox::Box:0x000055c8f3faf390>]>
ciphertext = lockbox.encrypt("hello")
=> "vy\xCE\xC7\xB1\x91\x8E\xFE\xCC\x84\xEFl\xE5\x9A\x93\x97\xD9l\xC8\xC3:\r\xE7o\etc..."
lockbox.decrypt(ciphertext)
=> "hello"
```

Any insights?

Comment: That looks like code you probably want in your controller rather than your view. That aside, are you sure in this case that ``@example.example.attributes`` is non-nil and contains encrypted goo? Can you edit your question to show where and how the encryption happens and to show the controller for ``step2``?

Answer (score 0):

For model attributes, make sure you're using the attribute key (the master key is never used to encrypt data directly).

```rb
key = Lockbox.attribute_key(table: "users", attribute: "email_ciphertext")
```

More info: https://github.com/ankane/lockbox/#key-separation

For convenience, you can also use:

```rb
User.decrypt_email_ciphertext(user.email_ciphertext)
```